# Searching for link in Outlook account

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have several accounts in my `Outlook 2016`. My primary company account is `Microsoft Exchange` and secondary is `Gmail`. I'm not happy about search functionality in emails that located in exchange. I would like to find emails that contain link `https://aa.bb` and Outlook not finds it `Exchange` account while finds in `Gmail` without problem. Why? How to solve this problem?

UPD

If I put link in quatation mark like `"https://aa.bb"` it finds. But why I need them?

Answer (score 0):

Check the fix in this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769651/outlook-search-returns-no-matches-found

Besides, if multiple users experience the search issue, it would be the server side search issue. Try to contact your administrator to check the server side status, or rebuild the index on mailbox server.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Since our server somewhere in Microsoft cloud i can't do anything in server sided. And this fix is not related to max Outlook 2013

Comment: Oh, how about searching in OWA? To the Max OS, as far as i know, it uses OS X’s Spotlight index to find the messages/item. Anyway, if you have advice about the products, just post it in the https://outlook.uservoice.com/.